# How to dynamically populate bootstrap carousel's slides as well as the indicators?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm in the process of building an image gallery. There is a set of images in a grid layout and the idea is that when one of those images is clicked, it launches a bootstrap carousel pop-up. The main (active) slide and list indicator should be the image that was clicked, the rest of the slides and indicators should be populated with pre-existing set of images that is within the grid. Is it possible to achieve this without using a separate set of images for the carousel?

Here's the code...

```
<div class="container">

   <div class="image-wrapper">
       <img class="image" src="image-1.jpg" />
    </div>
  
     <div class="image-wrapper">
       <img class="image" src="image-2.jpg" />
     </div>

     <div class="image-wrapper">
       <img class="image" src="image-3.jpg" />
     </div>

     <div class="image-wrapper">
       <img class="image" src="image-4.jpg" />

     </div>
        
  </div>
```

Bootstrap carousel (currently uses a separate set of images)

```
         <div id="custCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
            
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="active-img" src="image-1.jpg">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="image-2.jpg">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="image-3.jpg">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="image-4.jpg">
              </div>
            </div> <!-- Left right -->

            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#custCarousel" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon">
                &larr;
              </span>
            </a>

            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#custCarousel" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon">
                &rarr;
              </span>
            </a>

            <!-- Thumbnails -->

            <ol class="carousel-indicators list-inline">
              <li class="list-inline-item active"> 
                <a id="carousel-selector-0" class="selected" data-slide-to="0"
                  data-target="#custCarousel"> 
                  <img src="image-1.jpg"> 
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="list-inline-item"> 
                <a id="carousel-selector-1" data-slide-to="1" data-target="#custCarousel">
                  <img src="image-2.jpg"> 
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="list-inline-item"> 
                <a id="carousel-selector-2" data-slide-to="2" data-target="#custCarousel">
                  <img src="image-3.jpg"> 
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="list-inline-item"> 
                <a id="carousel-selector-3" data-slide-to="3" data-target="#custCarousel">
                  <img src="image-4.jpg"> 
                </a>
              </li>

            </ol>
          </div>
```

Comment: You'd use Javascript or jQuery. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Zim I've tried targeting the 'src' attribute of the 'active' and 'selected' classes in the carousel by using element.setAttribute('src', source) method. it only seems to work on the first instance of the slides and indicators.

Comment: Please show the code you've tried